# Why I can't deploy program on Solana Mainnet?

Tags: deployment, solana

Nowadays, I tried to deploy smart contract on Mainnet but I cant deploy it successfully.
why? and how can I deploy program on mainnet?

Answer (score 1):

The current tools perform a fee check on every single message sent to deploy the program, which can make things take much longer and timeout many of the signed transactions.

As a temporary workaround, if you're sure the funding account has enough SOL, you can use:

`solana program deploy --skip-fee-check <rest of your parameters here`

Comment: For redeploy case, is it possible? in this case how much sol do I need?

Comment: Certainly! For a redeploy, you'll need the same amount of SOL in your wallet as during the initial deployment, but in the end the cost will be very small.  You need enough SOL to create a new buffer account for the program, but after a successful redeployment, that SOL will be refunded